# how can I add add-row, delete-row for multiple tables

Tags: jquery, delete-row

I'm trying to Add and Delete rows in multiple tables. I have this working for a single table, but when I add more tables the add row button for table 1 adds rows to table 2 and the add row button on table 1 changes to the delete button.

I found this code online and am trying to modify it to fit my needs. I have some coding experience, but it's 10+ years since I've actually written an application. I was successful in changing .live to .on. I've used F12 to try to debug and have, I think, resolved all the bugs I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
<!-- ******** Size L ******************************************* -->
<table class="table size">
    <tr><td class="gapSize" colspan="3">L</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="gap">Qty of L</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td class="gap">Personalized L</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" class="sizeQty_L"  name="sizeQty_L" id="sizeQty_L" value="1" size="3" /></td>
        <td>
            <div class="table-repsonsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="gap">Number</td>
                        <td class="gap">Name or Monogram</td>
                        <td class="gap"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="sizeNumb_L" name="sizeNumb_L[]" id="sizeNumb_L" type="text" size="3" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input class="sizeName_L" name="sizeName_L[]" id="sizeName_L" type="text" size="20" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="add_L" value="Add Row" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" class="totPersonalize_L" name="totPersonalize_L" id="totPersonalize_L" size="3" value="0" /></td>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var xyz = 1;
        $('body').on('click','.del_L',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            xyz = xyz - 1;
            x = document.getElementById("totPersonalize_L");
            x.value = xyz;
        });
        $('body').on('click','.add_L',function(){
            $(this).val('Delete');
            $(this).attr('class','del_L');
            var appendTxt = "<tr>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input class='sizeNumb_L' name='sizeNumb_L[]' id='sizeNumb_L' type='text' size='3' value='' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input class='sizeName_L' name='sizeName_L[]' id='sizeName_L' type='text' size='20' value='' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input type='button' class='add_L' value='Add Row' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "</tr>";
            $("tr:last").after(appendTxt); 
            xyz = xyz + 1;
            x = document.getElementById("totPersonalize_L");
            x.value = xyz;
            maxqty = document.getElementById("sizeQty_L");
            if (maxqty.value == '') {
                alert('Total L is Empty');
            } else {
                if (maxqty.value < x.value) {
                    alert('Personalized L total [ '+ x.value +' ] is greater than Qty of L [ '+ maxqty.value +' ]\n\nQty of L will be updated');
                    maxqty.value = x.value;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- ******** Size XL ******************************************* -->
<table class="table size">
    <tr><td class="gapSize" colspan="3">XL</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="gap">Qty of XL</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td class="gap">Personalized XL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" class="sizeQty_XL"  name="sizeQty_XL" id="sizeQty_XL" value="1" size="3" /></td>
        <td>
            <div class="table-repsonsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="gap">Number</td>
                        <td class="gap">Name or Monogram</td>
                        <td class="gap"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="sizeNumb_XL" name="sizeNumb_XL[]" id="sizeNumb_XL" type="text" size="3" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input class="sizeName_XL" name="sizeName_XL[]" id="sizeName_XL" type="text" size="20" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="add_XL" value="Add Row" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" class="totPersonalize_XL" name="totPersonalize_XL" id="totPersonalize_XL" size="3" value="0" /></td>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var xyz = 1;
        $('body').on('click','.del_XL',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            xyz = xyz - 1;
            x = document.getElementById("totPersonalize_XL");
            x.value = xyz;
        });
        $('body').on('click','.add_XL',function(){
            $(this).val('Delete');
            $(this).attr('class','del_XL');
            var appendTxt = "<tr>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input class='sizeNumb_XL' name='sizeNumb_XL[]' id='sizeNumb_XL' type='text' size='3' value='' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input class='sizeName_XL' name='sizeName_XL[]' id='sizeName_XL' type='text' size='20' value='' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input type='button' class='add_XL' value='Add Row' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "</tr>";
            $("tr:last").after(appendTxt); 
            xyz = xyz + 1;
            x = document.getElementById("totPersonalize_XL");
            x.value = xyz;
            maxqty = document.getElementById("sizeQty_XL");
            if (maxqty.value == '') {
                alert('Total xL is Empty');
            } else {
                if (maxqty.value < x.value) {
                    alert('Personalized XL total [ '+ x.value +' ] is greater than Qty of XL [ '+ maxqty.value +' ]\n\nQty of XL will be updated');
                    maxqty.value = x.value;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you remove the 2nd table and script, you will see what I am expecting to see for each table. I expect Add Rows for size L to be in the first (L) table and Add Rows for size XL to be in the second  (XL) table.

If there's a more elegant way to handle this, I'd love to try it. I have to receive personalization information for sizes Youth XS up to adult 5XL, but assume that if I can get it working for 2, it will work for more sizes.

Comment: This is not a good idea to add more tables as per the size, instead of you should specify a select option for size ,like XS, S, L ... , could you please add sample expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add unique id to each table and then refer that id to add and delete rows in respective tables,

Please try following code.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table size" id="table_L">
    <tr>
 <td class="gapSize" colspan="3">L</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="gap">Qty of L</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td class="gap">Personalized L</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" class="sizeQty_L"  name="sizeQty_L" id="sizeQty_L" value="1" size="3" /></td>
        <td>
            <div class="table-repsonsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="gap">Number</td>
                        <td class="gap">Name or Monogram</td>
                        <td class="gap"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="sizeNumb_L" name="sizeNumb_L[]" id="sizeNumb_L" type="text" size="3" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input class="sizeName_L" name="sizeName_L[]" id="sizeName_L" type="text" size="20" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="add_L" value="Add Row" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" class="totPersonalize_L" name="totPersonalize_L" id="totPersonalize_L" size="3" value="0" /></td>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var xyz = 1;
        $('body').on('click','#table_L .del_L',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            xyz = xyz - 1;
            x = document.getElementById("totPersonalize_L");
            x.value = xyz;
        });
        $('body').on('click','#table_L .add_L',function(){
            $(this).val('Delete');
            $(this).attr('class','del_L');
            var appendTxt = "<tr>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input class='sizeNumb_L' name='sizeNumb_L[]' id='sizeNumb_L' type='text' size='3' value='' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input class='sizeName_L' name='sizeName_L[]' id='sizeName_L' type='text' size='20' value='' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input type='button' class='add_L' value='Add Row' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "</tr>";
            $("#table_L tr:last").after(appendTxt); 
            xyz = xyz + 1;
            x = document.getElementById("totPersonalize_L");
            x.value = xyz;
            maxqty = document.getElementById("sizeQty_L");
            if (maxqty.value == '') {
                alert('Total L is Empty');
            } else {
                if (maxqty.value < x.value) {
                    alert('Personalized L total [ '+ x.value +' ] is greater than Qty of L [ '+ maxqty.value +' ]\n\nQty of L will be updated');
                    maxqty.value = x.value;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<!-- ******** Size XL ******************************************* -->
<table class="table size" id="table_XL">
    <tr><td class="gapSize" colspan="3">XL</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="gap">Qty of XL</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td class="gap">Personalized XL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" class="sizeQty_XL"  name="sizeQty_XL" id="sizeQty_XL" value="1" size="3" /></td>
        <td>
            <div class="table-repsonsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="gap">Number</td>
                        <td class="gap">Name or Monogram</td>
                        <td class="gap"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="sizeNumb_XL" name="sizeNumb_XL[]" id="sizeNumb_XL" type="text" size="3" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input class="sizeName_XL" name="sizeName_XL[]" id="sizeName_XL" type="text" size="20" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="button" class="add_XL" value="Add Row" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="text" class="totPersonalize_XL" name="totPersonalize_XL" id="totPersonalize_XL" size="3" value="0" /></td>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var xyz = 1;
        $('body').on('click','#table_XL .del_XL',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            xyz = xyz - 1;
            x = document.getElementById("totPersonalize_XL");
            x.value = xyz;
        });
        $('body').on('click','#table_XL .add_XL',function(){
            $(this).val('Delete');
            $(this).attr('class','del_XL');
            var appendTxt = "<tr>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input class='sizeNumb_XL' name='sizeNumb_XL[]' id='sizeNumb_XL' type='text' size='3' value='' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input class='sizeName_XL' name='sizeName_XL[]' id='sizeName_XL' type='text' size='20' value='' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "<td><input type='button' class='add_XL' value='Add Row' /></td>";
            appendTxt += "</tr>";
            $("#table_XL tr:last").after(appendTxt); 
            xyz = xyz + 1;
            x = document.getElementById("totPersonalize_XL");
            x.value = xyz;
            maxqty = document.getElementById("sizeQty_XL");
            if (maxqty.value == '') {
                alert('Total xL is Empty');
            } else {
                if (maxqty.value < x.value) {
                    alert('Personalized XL total [ '+ x.value +' ] is greater than Qty of XL [ '+ maxqty.value +' ]\n\nQty of XL will be updated');
                    maxqty.value = x.value;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect! A small change makes all the difference in the world! Thank you.

Comment: @DancingBay you can accept the answer if it solves your problem.